# private_pub Rails doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

There is code for JS:

```
console.log('private_pub')
PrivatePub.subscribe "/messages/new", (data, channel) ->
  console.log(123)
```

And code for Rails:

```
    PrivatePub.publish_to "/messages/new", :chat_message => "Hello, world!"
    puts '12345'
```

I've got 'private_pub' message in JS and '12345' in console, but I've never got '123' in JS! What's wrong? How can I fix it? Rails 4.

Comment: What is PrivatePub? Do you have to configure it client-side so that it knows what to listen to?